# How to increment score only once even if radio button in radio group is clicked multiple times?

Tags: android, radio-button

I am developing a QuizApp. It consists of multiple choice questions with radio button as options. My problem is for example I am in question1 when I click on correct answer click on next button(question2) and again click on back button and go to question1 and click on correct answer my score is being incremented twice..Can any one help me am new to Android.. Thanks in advance.Below is my code.

```
 public class TrueFalseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        List<QuestionTrueFalse> questionTrueFalseList;
        int myscore = 0;
        int quid = 0;
        int id;
        TextView tv, txt1;
        QuestionTrueFalse curQues,c;
        RadioButton b1, b2;



        Button next;
        RadioGroup grp;

        RadioButton answer;
        String string;
        Button submit;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_trfal);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
            b1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            b2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);


            DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);

            grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);

            questionTrueFalseList = db.getAllTrFalsQuestions();
            if (questionTrueFalseList != null && questionTrueFalseList.size() != 0) {
                curQues = questionTrueFalseList.get(quid);
                setQuestionView();
            }


            next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.front);
            back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    //Next Button
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());


                    try {
                        if (curQues.getAnsw().equals(answer.getText())) {

                            myscore++;

                            Log.d("score", "Your score" + myscore);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select any option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    c = curQues;

                    if (quid < 19) {

                        quid++;

                        curQues = questionTrueFalseList.get(quid);
                        grp.clearCheck();
                        setQuestionView();



                    }
                    else {
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        timerHasStarted = false;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TrueFalseActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("score", myscore); //Your score
                        intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
    //Submit Button
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);
                    answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    // save();

                    try {
                        if (curQues.getAnsw().equals(answer.getText())) {

                            myscore++;
                            Log.d("score", "Your score" + myscore);

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select any option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    Intent intent = new Intent(TrueFalseActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", myscore); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();




                }
            });
    //Back button
            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (quid > 0) {
                        quid--;
                        curQues = questionTrueFalseList.get(quid);
                        setQuestionView();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
      private void setQuestionView() {
        tv.setText(curQues.getQues());
        b1.setText(curQues.getOpt1());
        b2.setText(curQues.getOpt2());

    }
    }
```

//My problem is when that when I select one correct answer option go to next question and come back to same question and again select correct answer my score is being incremented twice.am using radio buttons.How to solve this problem please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new boolean variable

```
boolean isIncremented=false;

//in you submit button change this logic
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //rest of the code

                try {
                    if (curQues.getAnsw().equals(answer.getText())) {
                        if(!isIncremented){
                         myscore++;
                         isIncremented=!isIncremented;
                        }

                    //rest of the code 
             }
 //inside your next button do the same
 next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //rest if the code


                try {
                    if (curQues.getAnsw().equals(answer.getText())) {

                        if(!isIncremented){
                         myscore++;
                         isIncremented=!isIncremented;
                        }

                        //rest if the code
                    }

//and don't forget to change the value of isIncremented set to be false again when new question is generated
```